# When ContentHash gives less performance over the other hash strategies?

Tags: javascript, caching, webpack, browser, hash

After reading about the following three hash strategies in `Webpack`:

- `Hash` - determined by the build itself. all the chunks have the same hash.
- `Chunkhash` - determined by the entry file and will determine any other chunk which came from that entry with the same hash.
- `Contenthash` - determined by the content of the chunk (leaving our the metadata in the calculation of the hash).

My only conclusion is that the first two hash strategies will cause the client to download unchanged chunks multiple times.

---

Can you give any explanation of why the first two hash strategies will bring better performance for the client over the last once?

Answer (score 0):

The cache works as an object, when a file is downloaded the browser goes to check if it has already any file with the same name.

Now, you sort of answered your question. When you generate a build with the first 2 strategies, publish them, then goes to modify its contents, publish again, the user will download eveything over again even though you have made one single modification.

When you use contenthash, the hash is going to be determined based on the content of that chunk, so the user is only going to have to download new files if you made any modifications, and just those files that were modified not the entire bundle.

Comment: Then why the first two options exist if no one should ever use them?

Comment: That question should be made to the creator of webpack, not to anybody else